# Alignment of several case environments at the equals sign

Tags: align

I have several consecutive case environments, each containing a pair of equalities.  Within each case environment, I have vertical alignment at the equals signs.  I would like all of the equalities to be aligned at the equals signs.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}rcl}
a^{6} + 2a^{3}b^{3} + b^{6} &{}={}& q^{2} \\
4a^{3}b^{3} &{}={}& -\dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{array}
\right.
,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}rcl}
a^{3} + b^{3} &{}={}& -q \\
a^{6} - 2a^{3}b^{3} + b^{6} &{}={}& q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{array}
\right.
,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}rcl}
a^{3} + b^{3} &{}={}& -q \\
(a^{3} - b^{3}){\vphantom{a^{3} + b^{3}}}^{2}  &{}={}& q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{array}
\right.
,
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{}rcl}
a^{3} + b^{3}   &{}={}& -q \\
a^{3} - b^{3}   &{}={}& \sqrt{q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}}
\end{array}
\right.
.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: My impression is that *no* alignment at equals signs is best, even in the same `cases` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember to *never* use consecutive math display environments: a sequence of `equation` environment should be a single `gather` (or `align`).

Here are three ways for doing your development of Cardan's formulas, getting worse from left to right (like “The Good, the Bad and the Ugly”).

[image]

There is no need to align the equals signs, in my opinion; just the braces should be aligned. Anyway, you find in the third `minipage` of the sample code the way for getting the worst one.

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,landscape]{amsart}

% enlarge the page just to fit three columns (unnecessary in a real production)
\addtolength{\textwidth}{6cm}
\calclayout

\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
&\begin{dcases}
a^{6} + 2a^{3}b^{3} + b^{6} = q^{2} \\
4a^{3}b^{3} = -\dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{dcases}
\\
&\begin{dcases}
a^{3} + b^{3} = -q \\
a^{6} - 2a^{3}b^{3} + b^{6} = q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{dcases}
\\
&\begin{dcases}
a^{3} + b^{3} = -q \\
(a^{3} - b^{3})^{2}  = q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{dcases}
\\
&\begin{dcases}
a^{3} + b^{3}   = -q \\
a^{3} - b^{3}   = \sqrt{q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}}
\end{dcases}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
&\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
a^{6} + 2a^{3}b^{3} + b^{6} &= q^{2} \\
4a^{3}b^{3} &= -\dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\\
&\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
a^{3} + b^{3} &= -q \\
a^{6} - 2a^{3}b^{3} + b^{6} &= q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\\
&\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
a^{3} + b^{3} &= -q \\
(a^{3} - b^{3})^{2}  &= q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\\
&\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
a^{3} + b^{3}   &= -q \\
a^{3} - b^{3}   &= \sqrt{q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}}
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\newlength{\widestleft}
\settowidth{\widestleft}{$a^{6} + 2a^{3}b^{3} + b^{6}$}
\newenvironment{myaligned}
 {\,\begin{array}{@{}>{\raggedleft$}p{\widestleft}<{$}@{}>{{}}l@{}}}
 {\end{array}}
\begin{align*}
&\begin{cases}
\begin{myaligned}
a^{6} + 2a^{3}b^{3} + b^{6} &= q^{2} \\
4a^{3}b^{3} &= -\dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{myaligned}
\end{cases}
\\
&\begin{cases}
\begin{myaligned}
a^{3} + b^{3} &= -q \\
a^{6} - 2a^{3}b^{3} + b^{6} &= q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{myaligned}
\end{cases}
\\
&\begin{cases}
\begin{myaligned}
a^{3} + b^{3} &= -q \\
(a^{3} - b^{3})^{2}  &= q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{myaligned}
\end{cases}
\\
&\begin{cases}
\begin{myaligned}
a^{3} + b^{3}   &= -q \\
a^{3} - b^{3}   &= \sqrt{q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}}
\end{myaligned}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

If you want it to look uglier than ugly, here is a way

```
\documentclass[draft,a4paper,landscape]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}

\newlength{\widestright}
\newenvironment{horriblesystem}[1]
 {\settowidth{\widestright}{${}=#1$}%
  \left\{\,
  \begin{array}{@{}r@{}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash${}}p{\widestright}<{$}@{}}}
 {\end{array}\right.}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{horriblesystem}{\sqrt{q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}}}
a^{6} + 2a^{3}b^{3} + b^{6} &= q^{2} \\
4a^{3}b^{3} &= -\dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{horriblesystem}
\\
\begin{horriblesystem}{\sqrt{q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}}}
a^{3} + b^{3} &= -q \\
a^{6} - 2a^{3}b^{3} + b^{6} &= q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{horriblesystem}
\\
\begin{horriblesystem}{\sqrt{q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}}}
a^{3} + b^{3} &= -q \\
(a^{3} - b^{3})^{2}  &= q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}
\end{horriblesystem}
\\
\begin{horriblesystem}{\sqrt{q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}}}
a^{3} + b^{3}   &= -q \\
a^{3} - b^{3}   &= \sqrt{q^{2} + \dfrac{4}{27} \, p^{3}}
\end{horriblesystem}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, don't use this! Your reader will be grateful. `;-)`

Comment: The third alignment is almost what I want.  I said that I wanted alignment at the equals signs, but I didn't say that I wanted the left braces aligned.  If I just remove the "&" before the "\begin{cases}" command, will I get the display that I want?  I have not heard of the "myaligned" environment. Can you suggest a web site that describes it?

Comment: @user143462 The `myaligned` environment is defined in the code. Just move the relative `\newenvironment` in your preamble, together with the `\newlength` and the `\settowidth` command. If you don't want to align the braces (which should be the only items to be aligned, actually), then a different solution is in order. But I think the rightmost display is the worst among the three and the way you'd like is still worse.

Comment: @user143462 I added the requested display. I have no doubt about the better way to print this.

Comment: Wow!  You really do not agree with my aesthetic tastes - at least in some aspects of displayed environments.  Beauty is in the eye of the beholder.  (American maxim)

Comment: @user143462 Besides, those equation pairs should be separated by words, so alignment becomes irrelevant.

Comment: I should have included the beginning of the argument.  The previous statement is "The following system of equations (in the variables a and b) have the same solution set:".

Comment: I have some questions about the commands that  you put in the preamble.  I looked on this web site for an explanation for the command "\newlength". It is a "LaTeX macro which defines a new length register, which holds a length as number and can be used for calculations." You do not have a number that follows "\widestright". I guess "\widestright" is the name of the command that is to define a length?  I did not find anything on web sites to tell me about it.  (I have not defined commands in LaTeX.)  What is "{${}=#1$}" in your command for \settowidth instructing LaTeX to typeset?

Comment: @user143462 I use `\settowidth` for setting the length: this sets the parameter to the width of the argument (the widest right hand side, including the equals sign).